Is it possible to allocate memory with mmap that OS can free as needed?
The Linux OS automatically utilizes free RAM to cache files read from disk to improve the performance of applications. When free RAM is increasingly consumed by private application memory the OS quietly drops data from this cache to make it available to applications instead.
Applications themselves often use their private memory to cache things such as data loaded from the internet or remote database results. The OS is not aware of the purpose of memory in each application so at best it can only move it to the swap when free memory is getting low. This means the application developer may need to be cautious about how much data to cache so as not to strain the system, especially when the developer knows many applications are running on the same system at a time.
Is there a way for a Linux application developer to cache data in such a way that the OS can drop it any time the overall system is getting low on RAM?
I've read about the technique of using MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS with mmap, but could it perhaps be combined with something like madvise and MADV_DONTNEED? Maybe it is not really possible and it's unclear how an application could be coded to safely handle a memory mapped buffer that suddenly disappears at any moment.
This question is closely related to these two questions:
System/OS Caching vs. Application Caching
What is the purpose of MAP_ANONYMOUS flag in mmap system call?

As long as your mmap'd region is backed by disk, it's always available to evict. If you want to provide hinting, yes, that's what madvise is for.

And for anonymous mappings I think MADV_FREE in man madvise sounds like what you want? One would probably have to devise a mechanism to correctly identify that data read from the memory region has been freed, maybe using one bit in each page set to 1 to indicate that it hasn't been freed yet and then checking it after every read/write from/to the page? I don't know how aggressively Linux actually frees such pages.
